# XSLT open other xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am about to merge XML files (and adding meta information) whose relative path is specified in my input XML file. The files I want to merge are located in a subdirectory called "files"
The structure of the input file is the following

```
<files>
   <file>
       <path>files/firstfile.xml</path>
   </file>
   <file>
       <path>files/secondfile.xml</path>
   </file>
</files>
```

The firstfile.xml and secondfile.xml have the following structure

```
    <tables>
        <table name = "...">
        ...
        </table>
        ...
    <tables>
```

I would like to put all table nodes of one file in a group and add meta information to it. So I wrote the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <tables>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tables>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name = "enrichWithMetaInformation" match = "file">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(./path)/tables">
                <xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tables">

    <group>
        <meta>
            ...Some meta data ...
        </meta>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./table"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>
```

For every file I get an error:

> The system could not find the file specified.

It states that an empty node set has been returned (so the file could not be loaded). Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this issue?

Cheers

Comment: @IanRoberts, when the argument to document() is a node, then the path is interpreted relative to the base URI of that node.

Comment: @MichaelKay I stand corrected, I do find the formal language of specifications rather hard to parse sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the base URI of the source document is known, for example by doing base-uri(/). This value is used for resolving the relative URI passed to document(), in the case where the argument is supplied as a node (or set of nodes).

Two common situations where the base URI is unknown are:

(a) if you supply the source document as an in-memory DOM

(b) if you supply the source document as an input stream or Reader with no known URI.

Comment: How can I achieve that (I'm new to the topic)
Like that:
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document(./path)" base="base-uri(/)">
    <xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

Or am I able to declare it in the stylesheet header?
Is it true that this is only possible with XSLT 2.0 (I have to use XSLT 1.0) as somebody writes here:
http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200305/post70610.html

Comment: Sorry, base-uri() is a 2.0 function. But if you tell us how the source document was supplied, it should be apparent.

Comment: The source document is supplied as an in-memory DOM

Comment: So, if this is Java, set the base URI using DOMSource.setSystemId(). If it's not Java, consult the relevant API. Alternatively, do you really need to supply the input as a DOM? If you let the XSLT processor build the tree in its own format, it will probably be much more efficient.

Comment: I use an ant file to do the transformation. So I have an input xml file and transform it using my stylesheet. So I do not have any "real" programming language code (only the input xml file and the stylesheet). The problem is that I don't know how to set the URI without using a programming language like Java

Comment: I don't think Ant supplies the input to a transformation as a DOM. If you're using Ant to drive the transformation, what makes you think it is using DOM?

Comment: As far as I have understood, Ant just takes the input file, creates an internal tree hierarchy and then applies the transformation. Honestly speaking, I have never thought about how Ant processes the file (so I thought the transformation is applied as a DOM). I simply used the XSLT task. Now I'm stuck at setting the internal base id. I think that this is the reason why addressing other files using relative paths does not work. At least I have not found any other hints that could explain why it does not work.

Comment: OK, so your information about it using a DOM was wrong. For a source file processed using Ant, I would expect the base URI to be known. Back to square one. I think we need more information about what the transformation is doing and how it is being executed.

Comment: The transformation takes an xml file as input, applies the stylesheet and produces an html file as output. I use ant 1.9.2. and a XSLT task to do the job. I am using XSLT 1.0 (so, the base-uri function does not work). So I cannot do:

`<xsl:template name = "enrichWithMetaInformation" match = "file"> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="document(./path)/tables" base="base-uri(/)">
<xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>`
And I do not know how I can make the processor resolve the URI running XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the processor cannot resolve the path dynamically. Can the processor evaluate `<xsl:apply-templates select="document(./path)">`to the correct path. Can it resolve the argument ./path to the value of the path element in the xml file?

Comment: If I try to print the relative path:
<xsl:value-of select = "document(./path)"/>, it does not print anything.

Comment: But Ant says, that the document function could not open the specified files. But the paths are correct. The files exist, but cannot be opened.

Comment: I figured it out. The files from outside were linking to some files that did not exist. So basically they were kind of corrupt. And this is of course the last place where you look for when you get an error like that. Thanks for your help. Otherwise it would have taken much longer to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the document() function should be a string. Get the node value for path in  variable concatting with the ./ and pass that in. I can do a quick test when I get to my computer but I think that is your issue. Here's an option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tables>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tables>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match = "file">
    <xsl:variable name="filepath" select="concat('./',path)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="tableprocessor">
        <xsl:with-param name="tables" select="document($filepath)/tables"/>
    </xsl:call-template>   
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="tableprocessor">
    <xsl:param name="tables"/>
    <group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$tables"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `document` works fine when its first argument is a node set, and it returns the union of the node sets that would result from calling `document` with the string value of each node in turn.

Comment: yes, that is correct also. I did test that too after i posted. I was using a variable for ease of debugging. that said, the above XSL works fine and processes exactly as expected for this sample.