# Stock the result of some xslt transformation, but don't output it

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

I want to use the result of some transformation I write in `XSLT`, but not output it.

Here is my MWE.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<foo xmlns="urn:t">
    <bar>text</bar>
    <ignored>i</ignored>
</foo>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="urn:t">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="var">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//foo"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:value of select="bar"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My intent is that I want to be able to use `$var` elsewhere in the sheet once I have created it.

When I run the thing, it outputs `text`.

How do I stock the result of a matching template in a variable, without outputting it?

Answer (score 0):

The global variable you have declared will probably only be evaluated at all if you use it somewhere. The output you get is not output from your variable but output from your template matching `foo` triggered by execution of the [built-in templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-rule), see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQi which is your code without the variable and produces that output. So you either need to override the built-in templates to do nothing, which would however be rather pointless, as you certainly want to perform some processing, or you need to run your code for your variable population in a different mode and then have the default mode do the other processing but have it not processing `foo` elements with `<xsl:template match="foo"/>`.

It might be better you explain in more detail what you want to achieve or show us where/how you want to use the variable, then it should be easier to make a suggestion that is not as radical as overriding the built-in templates to do nothing.

Comment: In a `catalog.xml` file, I wrote a list of xml files, with the uri stocked as an element for each file.

I want  to be able to write a `xslt` file, go fetch the `uri` information to one (or multiple files), and then run my `xslt` transformations on it, possibly from multiple xslt files, and then output it to a single file.

The part that is blocking me now is fetching the `uri` from the list, the rest I should be able to manage.

Comment: If you have a catalog.xml with some `uri` elements you want to select then `doc('catalog.xml')//uri` allows you to do that, I don't understand why that would require any templates. So I don't see any relation between your vague question and the problem you have now presented in the comment.

Comment: I found the answer of my problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469398/xslt-open-other-xml-files